What does "find your line" mean?
While driving in a car, Dom speaks to his son Little B on a walkie-talkie.
Little B is also driving with Dante:

Dom: Feel the car, find your line and fly.

Here “fly” means to escape from Dante and jump into his car, which is what happened
afterwards.
What does "find your line" mean?

That's not what fly means in this context, it just means go fast.

Agreed,  Using fly to mean escape is a bit of a poetical use of the word - it much more common for it to mean to move fast, or literally to be travelling through the air.

"Line" just means the path you intend to follow.
Mostly used in racing and referred to as the racing line, meaning the optimal path in relation to speed and safety.

The racing line is the route a racing driver follows to take corners in the fastest possible way. By using all of the available space on the track, cars can travel in a straighter line and travel faster before reaching the limits of grip. Determining the best line is an essential skill to master for both track days and racing events.

Source
